# how to set cluster-id in flink

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability

I want to use ha service in flink with Standalone kubernetes, but don't know how to set cluster-id for each flink cluster. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Link:
[high-availability-with-standalone-kubernetes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#high-availability-with-standalone-kubernetes)

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify what exactly you want ? In the example in your link, the first config option under `data: flink-conf.yaml:` is exactly `kubernetes.cluster-id: <cluster-id>`

Comment: I mean whether I should set a cluster-id for each flink cluster in advance, and use this id directly in yaml when setting ha service.

Comment: Could you please [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Additionally: are you using bare metal installation or some cloud provider?